# array reduce not correctly inferring types

Tags: arrays, typescript, reduce

i am having some troubles with array reduce in Typescript.
To simplify, let's say I have a simple array of numbers where I want to remove duplicates and return a new array without them I was used to do something like this using reduce:

```
const new = nums.reduce((acc, item) => acc.includes(item) ? acc : [...acc, item], [])
```

where:
nums = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
and new should be:
new = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

I have tried to type the function like this:

```js
const new: number[] = nums.reduce((acc: number[], item:number) => acc.includes(item) ? acc : [...acc, item], [])
```

I receive the following error for "new":

```
TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
```

and an error on the accumulator:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
```

Seems like there is no way of telling typescript that the accumulator should be an array of numbers, any solution?

Comment: Try with the Array constructor `const new: number[] = nums.reduce((acc: number[], item:number) => acc.includes(item) ? acc : [...acc, item], new Array<number>());`

Comment: I don't see a problem on the TS playground [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3igrgWzQC5t8AjEGAbQF0BuAKGXSxRAHdYZ4BeEggOjjAcYEAAoxUMGGK485KtQA08AJYYQeQnIUBKHgD54UsP1UpIOUGjHrN+gPzHp8YpX4eTKu3mXwauvRAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to reduce function types:

```
reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => U, initialValue: U): U;
```

The return value is inferred from the `initialValue`. So you can either cast `initialValue`:

```
nums.reduce((acc, item) => acc.includes(item) ? acc : [...acc, item], [] as number[])
```

Or rewrite template argument:

```
nums.reduce<number[]>((acc, item) => acc.includes(item) ? acc : [...acc, item], [])
```

Comment: Thanks that was something I missed

Answer (score 2):

Do this `nums.reduce<number[]>(...)` to tell TypeScript what reduce will return